# Use dynamic_cast to to validate pointer to polymorphic type

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

For some reasons in our application we could have pointers that was already deleted:

```
IPolymorphicObject* p_object = CreateObject();
```

Somewhere **p_object** will be deleted (via either **delete** or unloading module where it was allocated)

```
delete p_type;
```

Another code which uses saved value of p_object, let it be **mp_object**.

```
mp_object->SomeMethod();
```

Since mp_object is already removed - we have a crash.
I know that the best way is to switch to shared_ptr/weak_ptr, but now it requires a lot of refactoring, that is why I found another solution - how to check pointer validity.

I know that dynamic_cast will return pointer to the actual object offset in memory.

Also I know that dynamic_cast(p_invalid_pointer) will throw  an exception **non_rtti_object** which I can catch I thus write validation method:

```
template<class T>
bool IsPointerValid(T* ip_ptr)
{
try
{
dynamic_cast<void*>(ip_ptr);
}
catch(...)
{
return false;
}

return true;
}
```

Final code will look like:

if( IsPointerValid(mp_object))
  mp_object->SomeMethod();

I know that this will be very bad solution and should be avoided.

My questing is: will **IsPointerValid** always return false if pointer to polymorphic object is not valid?

Comment: I strongly suspect you are well outside the world of any guarantees here! Definitely by the language standard. Probably by the implementation. Which implementation is it, anyway?

Comment: And you added the C tag - why? C is not C++ is not C!

Comment: Using a stray pointer in any way, except to reinitialize it (i.e. assign it to point to something valid) will always lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Even if you find that the pointer contains the address of some "polymorphic object", it could easily be some *new* object that happens to reuse the deleted object's memory space.

Comment: I use implementation of dynamic_cast from Visual Studio 2013 x64 libraries. For all cases with invalid pointers it worked well. But I know that it is really implementation specific and depends on compiler/linker/target platform. I found that on Linux it will crash because pointer points on memory that is already free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is undefined behavior.

What you need to understand is that `dynamic_cast` requires a "valid" pointer. That is, a pointer to a "valid" object.

Given a pointer to an invalid object, an object that no longer exists, this results in undefined behavior.

Sometimes you will get true here. Sometimes you will get false. And sometimes you will get ["File Not Found"](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_) as the return value. That's what undefined behavior means.

Answer (score 1):

While moving to `shared/weak_ptr` will sure cost you a lot of time, solving the problem, and guaranteeing it won't return, will cost you

a. more time; you'll always end up in the 'I *think* the problem is solved' state, and never feel safe anymore.

b. customer satisfaction because you're not going to cover 100% of your source code.

Answer (score -1):

I hope you also have NULL-pointers checks prior to dereference those. In this case replace your delete by a macro DELETE which will invoke the real delete and also set the pointer to NULL. This will signal the followed software that the object is deleted and should not be used. In my opinion such replacement should not take significant efforts also in a relatively big project.

Comment: If you read the question carefully, it states that an earlier copy of the pointer has been made. Setting the pointer to NULL, after deletion, will accomplish absolutely nothing whatsoever, in terms of affecting some other unrelated pointer, somewhere else.

Comment: ah.. just have missing "uses saved value of"